# Proofreading scripts before running them

Tags: python, linux, debugging, vim

I make bad scripts and often do stupid things.

I can live with that but sometimes I run these scripts on clusters that give me and my co-workers limited time and space.

What is the laziest way to proofread my scripts so I don´t screw up for everyone?

E.g. is there a site like S.O. or software that checks for infinite loops or such things?

Comment: Why not test these scripts locally, before deploying them to the cluster?

Comment: [pylint](http://www.pylint.org)

Answer (score 4):

Is **[PyLint](http://www.pylint.org/)** what you are looking for ?

To quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pylint):

> Pylint is a source code bug and quality checker for the Python programming language. It follows the style recommended by PEP 8, the Python style guide.

But the most important part is the [error detection feature](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-messages). It will catch many "errors". Unfortunately, to quote Frédéric Hamidi in a comment below: *"PyLint won't detect infinite loops (which is pretty much impossible to do reliably in the first place)"*

It is nevertheless a good tool to run *before* going to peer code review...

Comment: Alas, PyLint won't detect infinite loops (which is pretty much impossible to do reliably in the first place).

Comment: @Frédéric Thanks for your comment. I was double-checking the "error list" as I was very skeptical about that particular feature. I've edited my answer to give you credit for this remark.

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my vimrc

```
autocmd FileType python nmap <buffer> <F5> :w<Esc>:exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)<CR>
```

While it won't prevent you from writing infinite loops it'll help you catch 'stupid' mistakes like typos etc.